# Split string with special character "|"

Tags: java, android

I have string am retrieving from API that contains a this character "|". I will like to split the string with "|" I tried several options but failed.

```
String response="The general String | Yesterday"; 
String splitResponse = response.split("|");
// also tried this 
reponse.split("(?<=|)"); //no success
```

Comment: Try `split("\\|")`

Comment: `split()`  will retrurn a `String[]` not `String` object.

Answer (score 0):

In order to split using `'|'` you need to remove the escape character using below.

```
String response="The general String | Yesterday"; 
    String []splitResponse = response.split("\\|");
    for(int i=0;i<splitResponse.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(splitResponse[i]);
    }
```

Split method split your string on `REGEX`.